# Solving Complex Quadratic equations

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

After working a few exercises on the topic, the questions become progressively harder. In this particular exercise I was asked to solve the equations. However I can't quite seem to break this problem as I did previously and I'll explain why.

---

The equation is as follows: $$z^2 + (1-i)z + (-6 + 2i) = 0$$

---

My thought was to use the general formula to get the value of $z$, however it doesn't seem to be the case, or isn't as straight-forward as previous quadratics I've worked with. Please do see my attempt and correct my mistakes whether it be on this question are any other thing in particular that I'm doing wrong, self-teaching is somewhat harder.

### My attempt:

Use the formula: $$x =  \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$

In my case, $a = 1, b = (1-i), c = (-6 + 2i)$

$$\therefore  z = -(1-i) \pm \frac{\sqrt{(1-i)^2 - 4(1)(-6+2i)}}{2(1)}$$

Which boils down to: $$z = -1+i \pm{\sqrt{12-4i}}$$

From here on I'm confused as to how to continue. Am I going completely off track?

Comment: The equation you wrote is $z^2 +b z^4 + c = 0$, note the $z^4$. It's a quadratic equation in $w = z^2$.

Comment: Do note: $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+2xy$. However for a complex number $(x+iy)^2=x^2-y^2+2ixy$. The quadratic formula is derived by completing the square of the quadratic polynomial. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Note that you are also misquoting the usual quadratic formula.

Comment: You have to set $z^2=y$

Comment: Thanks everyone! All is clear now, just needed that little push in the right direction.

Comment: $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \neq -b\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

Comment: Messed up the general equation there a little bit, didn't realise. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Also wanted to point out that's it's not $z^4$ but simply $z$. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
z^2 + (1-i)z + (-6 + 2i) = 0\\
\begin{align}
\implies z &= \frac{-(1-i) \pm \sqrt{(1-i)^2 - 4(-6 + 2i)}}{2}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left( i - 1 \,\pm \sqrt{1+ 2i^2 - i^2 +24 - 8i}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(i-1 \pm 2i\sqrt{2i - 6}\right)\\
&=  \left(\frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{2(i - 3)} \right)i - \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
$$

Always remember that the quadratic equation is just a result of "Completing the Square" for a general quadratic:
$$ az^2 + bz + c = 0\\
\implies z^2 + \frac{b}{a}z + \left(\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 +\frac{c}{a} = \left(z + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 - \frac{b^2}{4a^2} + \frac{c}{a}\cdot\frac{4a}{4a} = 0\\
\implies z + \frac{b}{2a} = \sqrt{\frac{b^2 + 4ac}{4a^2}}\\
\implies z  = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}
$$

Comment: @Juxhin: *I* wouldn't proceed. It's somewhat messy to simplify further.

Comment: I understand, the answers were coming up just like yours, however looking at them just boggled my mind so I thought I might've been doing something wrong. Thanks alot

Comment: @Juxhin: Please do note, however, that by some *simple* algebra, you can approximate the roots to $a \pm ib$ form. You can also try using polar coordinates.

Comment: However is it recommend to give the result using it's polar form when asked to solve the equation? The trouble I have most of the time is properly interpreting the question asked and sometimes am not sure whether the answer I'm presenting is the *best* one.

Answer (score 2):

First, substitute $y=z^2$, so the equation becomes $y+(1-i)y^2+-6+2i=0.$ Then apply the quadratic formula. Notice that the $a$ in the quadratic formula is $1-i$, $b$ is $1$, and $c=-6+2i$. After solving for y, we see that $z=\pm \sqrt{y}.$ And you should be able to finish it.

Comment: Thanks alot Kun, makes sense now. Complex numbers do mess with my head a bit.

Comment: You are welcome